# Customized View to xml

Tags: android, android-layout, android-canvas

I am making a game and I don't want the whole canvas to occupy the screen. Is there a way on how to put my class extending SurfaceView into xml?  I want to put it to xml so that I can adjust the position and size of the SurfaceView on the screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in src:

```
public class MySurView extends SurfaceView {
  public MySurView(Context context) {
    super(context);
  }
  // you must overide this constructor
  public MySurView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
  }
}
```

in xml:

```
<package.name.MySurView
    android:id="@+id/surview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
</package.name.MySurView>
```